# How to find what is causing "stretched frames" in Chrome Timeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, optimization

I'm trying to optimize the Javascript in our browser app to make sure that animations always run at 60fps. I'm using the Chrome (57) Timeline tool analyse bottlenecks. Many are well solvable, but I also encounter a few very mysterious phenomena:

The screen shot below shows an empty timeline (during a long running CSS transformation), but still the frame exceeds 16ms. Where do I find what is going on there?
[image]

The other weird phenomenon is shown below, where part of a function's logic has been moved into a requestAnimationFrame() statement. That logic is nicely moved along further in time, still it seems to stretch the whole frame to 21.3ms. Why is that happening?

[image]

I hope someone can shed some light on these cases.

Thanks!

Pascal